# Извлечение элементов из списка

Tags: scala

```
var x:List[Any]=List(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'f, 'g, 'h))
def LoopRandS(c:Int):Unit= {
  var n: Int = 0
  val y: List[Symbol] = List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'f, 'g, 'h)
  var list = List[Symbol]()
  if (c <= 0 || y.isEmpty ) print(y)
  else for(i<-1 to y.size) {
    for(m<-y){
      val R=Random.between(1,y.size)
      if(n==R) list=list.::(m)
      n+=1
    }
  }
  print(list)
}
```

Мне надо извлечь из данного списка заданное количество случайно выбранных элементов.Я че то вообще не понимаю,как это сделать адекватно,ерунду какую-то написал.Использовать можно только Random,остальное все писать руками,без функций по типу random.shuffle.
Результат должен быть по типу такого
res0: List[Symbol] = List('e, 'd, 'a)

Comment: создаешь функцию от списка и `n` (заданного кол-ва). Отдельно создаешь функцию от `n, m` создания `Set[Int]` из `n` рандомных элементов от 0 до `m-1` включительно. В 1й функции полученный set отображаешь на элементы списка по индексу. Создаешь unit-тесты (можно заранее сделать)

Comment: Не поздно ли?))

Answer (score 1):

```scala
import scala.util.Random

val list: List[Symbol] = List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'f, 'g, 'h)

@annotation.tailrec
def randomElements(n: Int, available: List[Int], acc: List[Symbol]): List[Symbol] =
  if (n != 0) {
    val index = available(Random.between(0, available.size))
    randomElements(n - 1, available.filterNot(_ == index), list(index) :: acc)
  else {
    acc
  }

println(randomElements(3, list.indices.toList, List.empty[Symbol]))
```

Хвостовая рекурсия.
list - заданный лист элементов.
n - количество элементов для извлечения.
acc - хранит случайно извлеченные элементы.
available - во избежании повторного получения одного и того же элемента, хранит не использованные индексы.

Объяснение: Функция работает пока **n** не достинет нуля. Если **n** не равен нулю, то получаем случайный доступный индекс из списка **available**, по этому индексу получаем элемент из **list** и добавляем в **acc**.

Уменьшаем **n**, исключаем использованный индекс из **available**, передаём новые данные рекурсивной функции.